# sorting series in angular highcharts issue

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts

I have a problem with sorting points in different series with highchart,
to explain my problem more Let's take this series for example:

```
[
{name: 'series one', value: 5 values},
{name: 'series two', value: 10 values}
]
```

This data in the "text" xAxis option,  will cause sorting issues because the array is a different length. Even if the first series has 5 values, it needs all 10 to show correctly.

because of this problem when I'm trying to make a chart with two series that have the "text" xAxis option, the chart lebel goes to the wrong axis.
sorting code that I use for example

```
  if(this.chartAxis.x.unit === "Text") {
              chartOptions.xAxis.categories = this.chartPoints.map(p => 
       p.xValue).filter((v:any, i:any, a:any) => a.indexOf(v) === i).sort(function(a:any, b:any) 

     { return (a > b) ? 1 : ((b > a) ? -1 : 0); });
             
            }
```

if anyone has any idea how to solve this please comment.

Comment: Hi, could you recreate your case at this simple [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/kufowxq8/)?

Comment: Hello, below an example of Chart showing a combination of a column and a line chart, using multiple y-axes, https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/combo-dual-axes                                                                                                                         lets take for example "Feb" month, if I removed the value of temp series  value "-14.9"  for this month, the data will be sorted wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I solved this problem by comparing series length to insert null values if needed into the array, in this case, both series will have the same length, and the sorting issue will be terminated.

code snippet for my solution :

```
 let pointsOfSerieTemp = sortedChartPoints.filter(p => p.serieId === serie.id);
      
      // compare arrays lenght to insert null values if needed
      
        let categories = this.chartPoints.map(p => p.xValue).filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i);
        let pointsOfSerieXValues = pointsOfSerieTemp.map(p => p.xValue);
        let missingXValues = categories.filter(x => !pointsOfSerieXValues.includes(x));
        missingXValues.forEach(x => {
          pointsOfSerieTemp.push({xValue: x, yValue: null, zValue: null, serieId: serie.id});
        }); 

        let pointsOfSerie = pointsOfSerieTemp.sort((a, b) => (a.xValue > b.xValue) ? 1 : ((b.xValue > a.xValue) ? -1 : 0));
```